# Save sort order to hidden field with sortable jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using this plugin (http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) to create a feature for a website where a user can add form fields on the fly.

The idea is that they will give the form a name (title), and then add a series for form fields. These form fields need to be drag and drop sortable (thus the plugin) so the user can rearrange the order.

Once they are satisfied with the order, they will click the "Create Form" button, and the data to create the form will be submitted.

The data itself will be stored in three tables. Table 1: Forms, Table 2: Fields, and Table 3: Forms_Has_fields. The Forms_Has_fields table will includes a sort_order column, which tells the system in what order to display the fields.

That's where this question is important: when a field is re-sorted using the drag and drop feature, I need a way to save the sort order in an  or some other form control so I can parse it with PHP and create the fields properly.

If this was in PHP, I would just keep everything in an associative array: ($fieldname => $sortorder), but that doesn't seem like it's an option in javascript. Ideally, I could keep this in an array in Javascript, and then when sumit was clicked, dump that array as a JSON to an  field, and POST it to PHP. But if that's possible, I don't know how to do it.

If there is another (more elegant) way to handle this, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. I am giving you the points because you answered my question; however I did find a more elegant way of doing it. The  is, in fact, the order and array already. There is no reason to create a separate array to manage what is being saved in what order because the  does it already. All you have to do is itterate through it with .each().

And, best of all, I didn't have to use global variables